# Changing category subject in short intervals

Tags: seo, keywords, meta-description

I would like to know if it is possible to not get penalised by google for changing the subject of a category entirely. I would like to swap a category that I have built on a webpage, for one with a more relevant (as of now) topic. Changing description, content and title etc... would this destroy my SEO? It has amassed backlinks of great quantity and quality over the course of time and I seriously would not like to have them wasted or passed with internal links as the page itself is invaluable.

Assume anchors to my webpage were all "<empty>" for convenience purposes. They are nothing particularly descriptive.

Comment: What do you mean by "category"?  Is it a single page or a group of pages?  If it is a group, how many?  Are you keeping all their URLs?

Comment: Is this a question of taking a high-ranking web page, deleting it, and putting a completely different web page in its place at the same url? That's how the question reads to me.

Comment: stephen - a group of pages. It is simply the title and meta tags optimised for the keyword and all the products filtered to show only ones which are labeled under the specified category name.

Comment: The usual thing to do would be to add the new category to your website with new URLs.   What are you hoping to gain by reusing the old URLs?  Do the URLs for the old category describe the old category?  If so, wouldn't it look weird to have different content under that old URL?

Comment: Since there were too many quality backlinks pointing to it, I wish to utilise those for the new one. The urls are not a problem, they do describe both