# Does mobile canonicalisation penalise page ranking

Tags: seo, canonical-url, keywords, rel-canonical

yesterday I asked the question given with the following link:

[Changing category subject in short intervals](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133131/changing-category-subject-in-short-intervals)

I basically asked whether changing the subject of a category page with backlinks applicable to two different keywords would be penalised if I were to change the content of it which would make it fitting to the other keyword.

I now have more of a hypothetical question:

case a) would changing the subject of an old category with backlinks on it to fit the subject of a "hotter" category and then canonicalising it with the "hotter" category page that already exists penalise page ranking (or not affect it at all)

case b) Would it somehow make it invalid to change the subject of the page with backlinks and then canonicalise it with another page that I made the page with backlink's content to fit to?

Think about it this way: I have a page about oranges and one about apples, and one old page about carrots. a) I changed the subject of carrots to oranges and canonicalised it with the orange page, b) I changed it again to fit to apples.

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: What does this have to do with mobile?

Comment: The page canonicalisation is effectively mobile, not as in cellphones but actually being mobile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing category subject in short intervals](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133131/changing-category-subject-in-short-intervals)